# multiple order statement rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to order posts. I would like to order posts randomly first, and then these random posts should be ordered by the no of upvotes.

I've tried:

```
@posts= @posts.order("RANDOM(), upvotes DESC").limit(10)
```

but this doesn't work. Please help.
Thanks!

Comment: I think conceptually, what you want is actually to order by up votes and then randomly... otherwise the upvotes will almost never matter.  Also, why do you need them ordered randomly?  If there are a sufficient number of upvotes spread across the posts then the random part should be limited to a handful of posts at a time and rarely will matter?

Comment: Yeah that's just how I want it. Please let me know if you have an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:

```
@posts=@posts.order("RANDOM()").limit(10).sort_by{|p| p.upvotes}.reverse!
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the way I would do it is like this:

```
Post.select("#{Post.table_name}.*, random() AS rsort").order("rsort, upvotes DESC").limit(10)
```

This basically just says, select all of the columns in posts table as well as a column named resort (which is a random number between 0 and 1).  Then order by the rsort column followed by the upvotes column.  Additionally you should be able to access the rsort attribute on the model instance afterwards.

P.S. Probably should come up with a better column name than rsort.